# Docker pull: `remove /.pivot_root347438920: device or resource busy`

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I'm trying to pull an image off GCR using docker, using:

`docker pull eu.gcr.io/<project>/<image>:<tag>`

However I keep getting the error:

`failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root347438920: device or resource busy`

After receiving the error all calls to docker returns:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

The output of `systemctl status docker` is:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled) 
Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-18 10:38:26 CEST; 14min ago 
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket 
Docs: https://docs.docker.com 
Main PID: 985 (dockerd) 
Tasks: 42 
Memory: 175.0M 
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service 
        └─985 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
Aug 18 10:38:25 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:25.329780734+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start." 
Aug 18 10:38:26 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:26.093178325+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address" 
Aug 18 10:38:26 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:26.219186657+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done." 
Aug 18 10:38:26 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:26.333584778+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=48a66213fe graphdriver(s)=devicemapper version=19.03.12-ce 
Aug 18 10:38:26 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:26.334733161+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization" Aug 18 10:38:26 emil-pc dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:38:26.389239911+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock" 
Aug 18 10:38:26 <my_name> systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine. 
Aug 18 10:46:05 <my_name> dockerd[985]: time="2020-08-18T10:46:05.342092783+02:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root557795275: device or resource busy"
```

I've tried restarting docker but to no avail. Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`? In some systems normal user cannot perform any docker operations until the user was added in docker group.

Comment: I already added the user to the docker group. I tried with `sudo` as well just in case. It turned out that my entire OS install was broken and had trouble mounting disks, so I reinstalled it.